# Is there a potential memory waste in Android's and Oracle JDK's TimSort when sorting a sub-range of an array?

Tags: java, android, timsort

I have been examining the TimSort algorithm implementation in both Android and Oracle JDK, and I noticed that when sorting a sub-range of an array, the temporary array used for merging is always ensured to have a capacity equal to half the length of the whole array. This seems to potentially waste memory when sorting a sub-range that is smaller than half the length of the whole array.

I wonder if this behavior is intended or if it is a possible oversight in the implementation. Has anyone else noticed this, and is there any way to optimize the temporary array size when sorting sub-ranges of an array in both Android and Oracle JDK?

I would appreciate any insights or suggestions on this issue. Thank you!

I tried sorting a sub-range of an array using TimSort in both Android and Oracle JDK, and I expected the temporary array used for merging to be resized to match the length of the sub-range rather than half the length of the whole array.

Comment: TimSort is a general stable sorting algorithm based on merge sort. Merge sort requires O(N) extra space.
If this doesn't suit your requirements I'd suggest you switch to use another sorting algorithm such as Quicksort or Heapsort that are inplace and will meet your memory requirements better.

Comment: I don't know TimSort well enough, but it looks like tmp array is initialized with size `min(a.length / 2, 256)`, so there is room for improvement, but mostly on small(-ish) arrays

Comment: Would be good to link to the implementations.

Comment: @AminM Looks like you misunderstood. They have an array of length N but only sort a sub-range of length n,. That should take only O(n) space, not O(N).

Comment: If n is proportional to N. Then O(n) = O(N)

Merge sort always requires space proportional to N to sort unfortunately.

Comment: @AminM n is independent of N (other than being limited by it), **not** proportional to N. This does **not** require space proportional to N.